# Homeomorphism between $SU(2)$ and rotations in $ S^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

In Artin, *Algebra*, Chapter 8, page 277, he talks about the following map:

$$ h\colon (SU(2)- \{\pm I \})   \rightarrow S^2 \times \theta $$ where $ \theta \in (0,2\pi) $ is compatible with the rotation group $ SO(3) $.

How does one prove that this is a homomorphism using the fact the $SU(2)$ is simply connected?

Comment: Try to clarify your question.  Do you mean "homeomorphism" rather than "homomorphism"?  What does "compatible with the rotation group" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible $h$ explicitly in coordinates.  $\mathrm{SU}(2) = \bigl\{ \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} z & w \\ -\bar w & \bar z\end{smallmatrix} \bigr) : z,w\in \mathbb C, |z|^2+|w|^2 = 1\bigr\}$ is clearly a 3-sphere in $\mathbb C^2 = \mathbb R^4$.  If you prefer real numbers, set $z = a+ib$ and $w = c+id$; then it is $\{(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb R^4 : a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 1\}$.  The points $\pm I$ are $(a,b,c,d) = (\pm 1,0,0,0)$.  Removing these points makes $1 - a^2$ invertible, and so we can map $\mathrm{SU}(2) \smallsetminus\{\pm I\} \to S^2$ by:
$$ (a,b,c,d) \mapsto (B,C,D) = \bigl( \frac b{\sqrt{1-a^2}}, \frac c{\sqrt{1-a^2}}, \frac d{\sqrt{1-a^2}} \bigr) $$
The remaining dimension is $a \in (-1,1)$.  I think this is the map that user72694 has in mind.

---

That said, I'm not entirely sure what "compatible with the rotation group" means.  Another possibility is the following.  Recall (or, rather, google a bit and find http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~westra/so3su2.pdf) that $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ acts transitively on $S^2$, via
$$  \begin{pmatrix} z & w \\ -\bar w & \bar z \end{pmatrix}
 \mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix} \Re(z^2 - w^2) & \Im(z^2 + w^2) & 2\Re(zw) \\ 2\Im(zw) & \Re(z^2 + w^2) & -2\Im(zw) \\ -2\Re(z\bar w) & -2\Im(z\bar w) & |z^2| - |w^2| \end{pmatrix} $$
Let $e_3 = (0,0,1) \in S^2$, and consider the map $X \mapsto Xe_3 : \mathrm{SU}(2) \to S^2$.  Reading off the coordinates, it is:
$$ H: (a,b,c,d) \mapsto \bigl(2(ac - bd), -2(ad + bc), a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2 \bigr)$$
if I haven't made an arithmetic error.  (Consistency check: $4(a^2c^2 + b^2 d^2 - 2abdc) + 4(a^2 d^2 + b^2 c^2 + 2abcd) + a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + d^4 + 2 a^2 b^2 + 2 c^2 d^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 - 2a^2 d^2 - 2 b^2 c^2 - 2 b^2 d^2 = a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + d^4 + 2(a^2 b^2 + a^2 c^2 + a^2 d^2 + b^2 c^2 + b^2 d^2 + c^2 d^2) = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2 = 1$.  Good.)

The stabilizer of $e_3$ is the set of pairs $(z,w) \in \mathbb C^2$ such that $0 = \Re(zw) = \Im(zw)$ and $|z|^2 - |w|^2 = 1$.  Then $zw = 0$, so at least one of $z$ and $w$ vanishes, but $|z| \geq 1$, so $z\neq 0$, so $w = 0$.  Thus the stabilizer of $e_3$ is the set $\{(z,0) \in \mathbb C^2 : |z|^2 = 1\}$, which is the circle group $U(1) = S^1$.

This shows that $H: \mathrm{SU}(2) \to S^2$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $S^1$, and in fact $S^2$ is the homogeneous space $\mathrm{SU}(2)/S^1$.  This is called the **Hopf fibration**.  It is not a product map — the fiber $S^1$ "twists around" as you move around the base $S^2$.

However, if you restrict $H$ to $\mathrm{SU}(2) \smallsetminus \{\pm I\}$, it wouldn't surprise me if you do get a global product structure.  You'd have to do a bit more calculation to check.

Answer (score 0):

The homeomorphism $h$ can be viewed as follows. $SU(2)$ is a 3-sphere, and removing a pair of points gives a space that fibers over the equatorial sphere $S^2\subset S^3$. This is obviously homeomorphic to $S^2\times I$ in a fashion equivariant with respect to rotations of $S^2$, i.e. $SO(3)$.